# Android play two different songs on different earphones at the same time

Tags: android, audio, bluetooth, audiotrack, headphones

I need to play different audio at the same time, one to the normal earphones and another one to the bluetooth earphones. (on Android...)

someone know if i can do this? how?

thanks!

Comment: AFAIK android doesn't support multiple head sets at the same time. So maybe you can't.

Comment: you can use `Gstreamer`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

android has three Streaming Types:
Ringtone & Notification, Media and Alarm.
you can use them to play different sounds but you can't play them in same time. there is an priority rank.